# Using a java method in Qt that returns double array

Tags: qt, qandroidjniobject

I want to use java code inside my Qt Android app.

So, I use a QAndroidJniObject with the method callMethod, and it is supposed to return a jdoubleArray.It takes a const char argument.

```
QAndroidJniObject javaCode = QAndroidJniObject("/myJavaCode");
    jdoubleArray result = javaCode.callMethod<jdoubleArray>("detect", "([C)[D", buffer_java);
```

I don't know why but it doesn't compile, but I saw some examples with int that seemed to works fine.

```
error: undefined reference to '_jdoubleArray* QAndroidJniObject::callMethod<_jdoubleArray*>(char const*, char const*, ...) const'
```

Thanks for your answers

Pierre

Comment: Try to get a minimal proof-of-concept to work. Start with method which takes no arguments and returns void. Then change to method returning integer. Then try with that array. If these all work, then the problem is with your real project, try to figure out what's different there. But if you don't get even the simplest version to work, try asking a question about that, providing [mcve] in the question.

Comment: I tried with a jdouble and that worked...